# Is there a utility similar to "apt-file" that can search source packages?

Tags: apt, deb, packaging

I'm looking for a utility similar to `apt-file` that allows me to search the contents of source packages for certain files, rather than just binary packages.

Is such a utility available for Ubuntu?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 4):

`apt-file` is a simple wrapper for downloading the `Contents-<ARCH>.gz` files from a given Debian repository, then unpackaging and `grep`ing through them. `Contents` files are generated server-side (with great computional intensity) by merging the paths of all `deb` packages in the archive.

The specification for Debian repositories has no location reserved for a summary of all source package paths, and no implementation (`apt-ftparchive` and Launchpad's homebrewed method) has any facility for generating one.

If you really, *really* want this functionality, you could easily compile it yourself. Make this script, make it executable, and run it. It will take forever and eight days, but its output will be equivalent to a `Source-Contents` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

for PKGNAME in $(apt-cache pkgnames); do
    apt-get source $PKGNAME >> log
    for LINE in $(find $PKGNAME-*); do
        echo "$LINE $PKGNAME"
    done
done
```